# Is there a way get Objective-C version from command line or from code?

Tags: objective-c, macos, command-line

Is there a way to find Objective-C version in macOS from the command line or during runtime?

Comment: What do you mean "objective-c version"? It is 2.0 version since 2007 year. Maybe it is better to describe the original problem that you solve?

Comment: I want to display the language version in which the program is written and compiled when I run the command line tool.

Comment: But why? I don't think obj-c lang version ever changed due to active development of Swift and current immutability statistics of obj-c version number for the last 12 years. Relax and hardcode :)

Comment: Overengineering I can see :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLog(@"%d", OBJC_API_VERSION);`

OBJC_API_VERSION is defined in objc-api.h, you can read this file if using command line.

but the result will almost 2.